# how to read the number of columns in text file in java

Tags: java

how to read the number of columns in text file in java.

Example text file as below. Comma separated. In this i need to get the total column as count 4

```
ABC,BBC,12-10-2018,1234
ABC,BBC,12-10-2018,1234
ABC,BBC,12-10-2018,1234
ABC,BBC,12-10-2018,1234
```

Comment: Just split first line by "," and get the size of resulting array or simply count the number of "," in it and add one to it. You can use also some .csv lib, but it is not necessary for such an easy thing as to get number of columns

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm or actual code?

Comment: Actual Code please. It helps me lot

Comment: Like @SergeiSirik said, `int columns = line.split(",").length;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a Scanner and read the 1st line. 
By using `split()` with `,` as a delimeter you get an array and its length is what you want.

```
public static int getFileColumnsNumber(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner scanner;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }

    int number = 0;
    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        number = scanner.nextLine().split(",").length;
    }
    scanner.close();
    return number;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "test.txt";
    System.out.println(getFileColumnsNumber(filename));
}
```